# nginx cannot access domain

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, k3s

the load balancer and ingress controller are working fine.

I install Nginx deployment and Nginx service, then expose Nginx deployment to port 80

```
#kubectl describe ing minimal-ingress

- Name:             minimal-ingress
- Namespace:        default
- Address:
- Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
- Rules:
  - Host             Path  Backends
  - ----             ----  --------
  - mywebsite.com 
  -                 /   nginx-deployment:80 (10.52.2.38:80,10.52.2.39:80)
- Annotations:       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
- Events:            <none>

it's working fine when I access my Nginx through my deployment IP address:

> #curl 10.52.2.38
```

I accessed through the command line and browser it's working fine, with or without specifying port 80.

just `10.52.2.38` or `10.52.2.39`

but when I try to access use my host domain I showing

> #curl mywebsite.com

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to  mywebsite.com port 80: No route to host

I am also cannot do curl to localhost or IP localhost 127.0.0.1
it is only working on my IP pods

I flush my iptables and disable ufw
I add my domain to /etc/hosts and put my loadbalancer IP there

but still not working.

thank you, I am kubernetes K3S user.

Finally, I got the answer to my problem.
what are you need to add is ingressClassName:nginx

so basically it would look like this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

good luck everyone

Comment: try `curl -v mywebsite.com` to show more details

Comment: are you running the curl in a kubernetes container?

Comment: the curl -v mywebsite.com goes to access my Load Balancer IP address and showing no route to host

Comment: yes I run in Kubernetes cluster and run the nginx deployment inside of the cluster